# GetComboBoxinfo API failing with error code 87 in 64 Bit OS

Tags: winforms, combobox, 64-bit, hook

I am trying to hook mouse events to combobox. sample code is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KyfHS5Je8LVfNMpcVTc5FGDhll0Aa6p9).

But it is working fine if keep project properties [Prefer 32 bit TRUE] but GetComboBoxInfo API is failing with error code 87 if i keep Prefer 32 bit FALSE.

Here is place where code is failing:

```
public static IntPtr GetChildListWindowHandle(Control ctrl)
        {
            Win32.ComboBoxInfo comboBoxInfo = new Win32.ComboBoxInfo();
            comboBoxInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(comboBoxInfo);

            Win32.GetComboBoxInfo(ctrl.Handle, ref comboBoxInfo);
            uint error = GetLastError() ;

            if (true == Win32.GetComboBoxInfo(ctrl.Handle, ref comboBoxInfo))
            {
                return comboBoxInfo.hwndList;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ComboBoxInfo
        {

            public uint cbSize;

            public RECT rcItem;

            public RECT rcButton;

            public IntPtr stateButton;

            public IntPtr hwndCombo;

            public IntPtr hwndEdit;

            public IntPtr hwndList;
        }

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hwndCombo, ref ComboBoxInfo info);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code here, a [MCVE].

Comment: Hi Reza, Attached code in link is the minimal code. It contains a simple form.When the program is run you will hit  the problem directly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your Win32 declarations here. Always use `SetWindowLongPtr` and `GetWindowLongPtr` to get/set the styles. When the environment is 32Bit, these functions auto-fallback to the 32 bit version.

Comment: @Jimi added win32 declarations.Thanks

Comment: `stateButton` is an `int`, not `IntPtr`. You're also hooking (for some reasons) WndProc using 32Bit functions only (I gave a look at the project ). See my previous comment.

Comment: I'ld prefer `cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<COMBOBOXINFO>();`. It looks like this code comes from the past...

Comment: @Jimi - Yes true..this is legacy..;) I tried changing as per your suggestions but still no luck..

Comment: Well, if you changed something, then post the code you've changed. Also, you don't need all the hooking proc. If you really want to, maybe follow this other path: [SetWindowSubclass](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass). Or override `WndProc` of the `NativeWindow` class (and set the handle returned by `GetComboBoxInfo`). All your function calls must support 32/64 bit. The same goes for [Get/SetClassLongPtr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptrw), for example. And anything that follows.

Comment: @Jimi Excellent after changing win 32 api's 64 bit compatible it worked and need to change stateButton from IntPtr to int. Thanks once again for your inputs.